# Solder multiple microphone cables

Tags: soldering, cables, microphone

so I want to build a program that is going to turn on specific microphones through out the building. But that is not the problem, the problem is that I obviously need multiple microphones to place through out that building. So can I solder multiple microphone cables to regular 3.5mm microphone jack and will the pc detect it? If no can you tell me how I can do it. Sorry for grammar mistakes. :)

Comment: You need a *mixer*, and one that can be controlled by a PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, soldering multiple microphones in parallel will likely create impedance problems the computer interface is not expecting.  Further, it would be impossible to select an individual microphone.

Searching for "multiplex microphones" results in many hits.  [Here](http://www.av-iq.com/AVCat/images/documents/pdfs/MX399intro.pdf) is the first one.